# Add Icons next to SVG Text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts

I want to add 2 icons next to a svg text ( image attached, the node text/name will have diff length ), i know we could use an foreignObject but when using foreignObject i'm not able to get the node values

[image: sample img]

```
var addSvgCnt = nodeEnter.append("g")
     .attr("class",  "txt-swap-parent");

addSvgCnt.append("foreignObject")
   .attr("width", 1)
   .attr("height", 30)
   .append("xhtml:div")
   .attr("class", "svg-node")
    .html("<img src='https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_356964.png' height='10' width='10'/>
           <span>BRANCH1.2</span>
           <img src='https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_356964.png' height='10' width='10'/>");
```

here instead of BRANCH1.2 i need the node text, i tried psuedo elements but it's not working either. what is the best solution to achieve this

Comment: You have [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) and [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Texts) in SVG as well.

Comment: but when i add svg text and svg image, how do i position those three elements like in the image above, the node text could be diff in length. @JavaScript

Comment: By using `text.textLength`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon looks so much like [this unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2295/index.htm), you might even replace it and just use `tspan`:

Try clicking the nodes to see that clicks are registered correctly.

```js
const someText = "Hi from branch 1";
const circledPlusUnicode = "\u2295";
const x = 50, y = 100;

const text = d3.select("svg")
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", y);

text.append("tspan")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .text(circledPlusUnicode)
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("click circle 1");
  });

text.append("tspan")
  .attr("dy", 2)
  .attr("dx", 2)
  .text(someText);

text.append("tspan")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("dy", -2)
  .attr("dx", 2)
  .text(circledPlusUnicode)
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("click circle 2");
  });
```

```css
.circle {
  fill: darkgrey;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

---

Otherwise, you use `getBBox`, which returns a bounding box of the element it's called on, and you can use that to just position the image right next to the text:

```js
const someText = "Hi from branch 1";
const circledPlusImg = "https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_356964.png";
const x = 50,
  y = 100;

const textGroup = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate" + [x, y] + ")");

textGroup.append("image")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("href", circledPlusImg)
  .attr("height", 14)
  .attr("width", 14)
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("click circle 1");
  });

const text = textGroup.append("text")
  .attr("dy", 12)
  .attr("dx", 16)
  .text(someText);

textGroup.append("image")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("href", circledPlusImg)
  .attr("height", 14)
  .attr("width", 14)
  .attr("x", function() {
    const bbox = text.node().getBBox();
    return bbox.x + bbox.width;
  })
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("click circle 2");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```